# In a multi-goal maze, is it possible for DFS to find a path to a goal that is not the closest goal, while searching fewer nodes than BFS?

Tags: java

I'm writing a very simple pacman code, and I got this question on my mind, In a multi-goal maze, is it possible for DFS to find a path to a goal that is not the closest goal, while searching fewer nodes than BFS?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. Take, for example, the following "maze" (`x`s are walls, `!` is the start and `+` is a goal);

```
x!xxxxx
x     x
x     x
x     x
+     x
xxxxx+x
```

A DFS might start walking right until it hits the wall, then walking down, until it hits the goal:

```
x!xxxxx
x12345x
x    6x
x    7x
+    8x
xxxxx+x
```

Thus, it visits 9 nodes (`s` not included, `g` included) and finds a goal in distance `9`.

BFS, on the other hand, will expand "in circles".

1st step:

```
x!xxxxx
x1    x
x     x
x     x
+     x
xxxxx+x
```

2nd step:

```
x!xxxxx
x12   x
x2    x
x     x
+     x
xxxxx+x
```

3rd step:

```
x!xxxxx
x123  x
x23   x
x3    x
+     x
xxxxx+x
```

4th step:

```
x!xxxxx
x1234 x
x234  x
x34   x
+4    x
xxxxx+x
```

BFS visits at least 11 nodes (the 10 "marked" ones, plus the goal) and finds a goal in distance 5.

Comment: That really does make sense, thank you!

Comment: @Tugsuu Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)